# Как убрать лишние ссылки в header сайта

Tags: wordpress, header

Хочу оптимизировать код.
При открытии моего сайта в `view-source` браузера отображаются много лишних ссылок, на которые ругается например PageSpeed Insights:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='shortcodes-css'  href='http://mysite.net/wp-content/themes/deals/functions/shortcodes/shortcodes.css?ver=4.4.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fancybox-css'  href='http://mysite.net/wp-content/themes/deals/includes/css/fancybox.css?ver=4.4.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jq-ui-css'  href='http://mysite.net/wp-content/themes/deals/css/jquery-ui.css?ver=4.4.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='color-css'  href='http://mysite.net/wp-content/themes/deals/css/color-orange.css?ver=4.4.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='responsive-css'  href='http://mysite.net/wp-content/themes/deals/css/responsive.css?ver=4.4.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='custom-css'  href='http://mysite='all' />
```

Они генерируются с помощью функции **wp_head();**

Тоже самое с ссылками Javascript.

Как можно отключить их все с header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти сылки не лишние ни разу, без подгрузки этих стилей тема работать не будет. Все, что можно сделать, найти вызовы enqueue_style в теме и попытаться изменить один аргумент, чтобы загрузка этих стилей шла в подвале. Но это чревато, и, скорее всего, тема работать все равно перестанет.

Нет универсальных рецептов на все случаи жизни, поэтому слепо следовать рекомендациям PageSpeed не стоит. Google дает рекомендации для максимально широкого перечня платформ, и то, что хорошо для одного случая, не всегда стоит применять в другом.

Вам что нужно? Быстрый сайт или виртуальные очки PageSpeed? Скорее всего, первое. Так по опыту я вам скажу, что эти стили в заголовке не влияют почти никак на скорость загрузки, а долботни с ними вагон.

Чаще всего надо сжимать изображения, уменьшать размер контента, сжимать стили и скрипты, уходить от ajax и iframe по возможности, настраивать кеши, делать все на vps в конце концов и т.д. и т.п.

Вот эти вещи - реальный прирост скорости. А причесывание стилей в заголовке - чаще всего впустую потраченное время. Посмотрите waterfall в Pingdom и вы увидите, где у вас основные задержки при загрузке страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Через вызов `remove_action` можно удалить ненужные нам данные:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' );
```

Вот список всего, что можно удалить из хедера:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 ); // Удаляет ссылки RSS-лент записи и комментариев
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 ); // Удаляет ссылки RSS-лент категорий и архивов

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' ); // Удаляет RSD ссылку для удаленной публикации
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link' ); // Удаляет ссылку Windows для Live Writer

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0); // Удаляет короткую ссылку
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' ); // Удаляет информацию о версии WordPress
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 ); // Удаляет ссылки на предыдущую и следующую статьи

// отключение WordPress REST API
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rest_output_link_wp_head' ); 
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links' );
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'rest_output_link_header', 11, 0 );
// устаревшие функции
// используйте только для WordPress до версии 3.2 включительно 
if ( get_bloginfo('version') <= '3.2' ) {

    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link', 10, 0 ); // Удаляет ссылки на предыдущую и следующую статьи
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'index_rel_link'); // Удаляет ссылку на главную страницу 
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0 ); // Удаляет ссылку на родительскую страницу 
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0 ); // Удаляет ссылку на первую запись

}
```

Comment: У меня это всё было и я его таким путём удалил уже. Но вот остались те ссылки, которые я написал выше

Comment: @Ector это ссылки ресурсов WP и плагинов. Я бы советовал лучше вообще снести wp_head и самому прописать подключение ресурсов. Я делал так.

Comment: Но эти мои ссылки на файлы css обязаны вообще быть подключены в хедере? просто если эти подключения убрать, то ломается сайт.

Comment: @Ector, потому и ломается. Слушайте что **KAGG Design** говорит. Цифры в гугломерляке - [бред по большей части](http://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=945499). Хотите 100/100? Нет ничего проще - [503 и нет проблем](http://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?p=14920994#post14920994) :)

Comment: @SeVlad снести CSS в конец боди - реально бред. А по остальной части можно и прислушаться. В любом случае, в любых вопросах нужно думать своей головой. Не для каждого проекта эти советы подойдут.

Comment: @Vadizar, из полезного там только сжатые картинки. Всё остальное - чушь потому как во первых всё индивидуально. Во вторых слейка скриптов в 90% просто поломает сайт, в третьих - бредовые "рекомендации"  про сжимание внешних скриптов (даже на  свои ругается). Но даже css на 10мб не влияет на его показатели.  И какая польза от этих цифр? Нужно смотреть на реальную скорость загрузки, на ошибки  тд. Тот же пингтомтулз  про это всё скажет и даже больше. Включая и цифры гугломерялки.

Comment: @SeVlad хорошая заметка про бред в гугломерялке. Раньше не видел, но готов подписаться под каждым словом.

Comment: @SeVlad ну скрипты не будут ломаться, если их подключать в правильной последовательности - сначала внешние библиотеки, потом свой код, а в самом конце - вызовы. И тогда те же диаметрально противоположные 90%, при которых код не ломается. Ну а то что, что ругается на собственный скрипт AdWords - это реально фейл)

Comment: @Vadizar :))) Теория хороша на доске :). А в реальности - будут. Будут прото потому, что в реальности 99,9% адмнов ВП слейку делают пагинами-минификатороами. Даже если в них задавать исключения - это работа, которая всё рано ничего не даст. Я уже не говорю про ручное перелопачивание плагов/тем. И это не теория, и не чтение ГС-бложиков - это результат многолетнего участия на оф форуме (и др форумах) ВП. Видно какие проблемы у юзров в реальности.

Comment: @SeVlad просто сколько минифицирую JS, то проблемы реально был лишь с порядком. А разница, грузятся скрипты по отдельности, или в одном файле, но в том же порядке, нет. Правда я пользуюсь Uglify, а вот все тот же Google Closure Compiler - тот еще бред. Размер становится больше, а функционал не работает)